# Node JS (-bash: fork: Cannot allocate memory)

Tags: command-line, nodejs, memory-usage

Here's the Node JS I'm running at the beginning of the script to clear the garbage collector and then logging the available space:

```
global.gc();
var bytes = process.memoryUsage().rss;
var GB = (bytes / 1073741824).toFixed(5);
g.heapMessage = "MEMORY used in bytes: " + bytes + ", in GB: " + GB + ",  custom message: " + m;
```

Here's the output to the shell:

```
JavaScript Extracted

JavaScript Processing
MEMORY used in bytes: 27869184, in GB: 0.02596,  custom message: INIT epochProp
^Z
[7]+  Stopped                 sudo ./runScript
oughtimpliescan1@ubuntu:~$ sudo ./runScript
-bash: fork: Cannot allocate memory
oughtimpliescan1@ubuntu:~$
```

[image: memory fork screenshot]

As you can see, there's plenty of memory, 0.02596 GB... and yet the shell keeps telling me it cannot allocate memory, I've tried the [1,2,3](https://www.tecmint.com/clear-ram-memory-cache-buffer-and-swap-space-on-linux/) of this command:

`sync; echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches`

and I'm still having this issue, anybody know what's going on?

Comment: Also related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43652021/bash-fork-cannot-allocate-memory and https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-server-73/bash-fork-cannot-allocate-memory-4175615868/ – +1 for a well-written question btw, that's how you do it!

Comment: I've already found these responses, not sure what to do with them as this is happening after a few processes, aka I'll turn off the machine, turn it back on and run a process, it works but then the second or third time it will become clogged by something...  I looked at the swap memory but it doesn't make sense that would be the problem...  I can try setting ulimit to unlimited for all metrics I suppose... any other ideas?

Comment: Could you please open a [new question](/questions/ask) if you have a new or follow-up question? The comment section is not suitable or meant for new questions or extended discussion. You’re welcome to send me a comment with a notification to draw my attention to it. Thanks.